# How to connect remote database using local wamp?

Tags: mysql

I have a Joomla website configured in my local wamp. I have another server where my database resides. Now I want to connect that database into my local wamp to run my website. I have tried following in `configuration.php`.

I have applied all the required permission to remote server

```
public $host = 'xx.xx.xx.xx';
public $db = 'database_name';
public $user = 'username';
public $password = 'password';
```

I also used wild card (%.%.%.%) on remote database server. But unfortunately I am not able to connect it.

Can anyone help me to sort out this issue?

Comment: The server itself must be configured to accept external connection for that specific user. Is this what you mean when you said you have  "applied all the required permission to remote server"?

Answer (score 1):

The most likely issue here is that in your external MySQL database, the "username" account does not have the "host" field set to "%" (means any host)... If it's set to "localhost", then only local connections will be allowed.

Also, check my.cnf to make sure you are not binding the external MySQL database to 127.0.0.1. It should be bound to 0.0.0.0 (all IPs).